# Laravel DIR structure for backend / frontend / API

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel.
I am developing an application which is going to be an Web (laravel8 + vue.js) + Mobile App (Android).
Application has both backend and frontend on both web and mobile app.
Which means I need routes for web application to manage backend and frontend and API routes to manage same.
So, I was thinking how I should structure my code in Laravel to reduce code redundancy and what is best approach to plan my project DIR structure, routes etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Jetstream as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at and consider using Laravel Breeze or Laravel Jetstream with the Interia.js & Vue.js stack. Here is the info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits.

While both of these kits come with Inertia.js (Breeze only if you include it during installation), you don't have to use it and can use Axios or whatever you prefer.

These kits offer scaffolding with the routes, controllers, and views you need to register and authenticate your application's users and you should be able to easily build you API on top of either for the mobile app.

Comment: Yes, right I can do that but what I am thinking of keeping code structured, easy, clean, and avoid redundancy.

For eg:

Posts 
    - Backend 
         PostsController.php
    - Frontend
         PostsControllers.php

and all the code for web and API goes into these files.

Comment: Yes this would not be a problem. With Jetstream controllers are by default located in ```app\Http\Controllers``` and you could create directories for your front end and back end controllers within this ie. ```app\Http\Controllers\front-end``` and ```app\Http\Controllers\back-end```, then reference the appropriate controllers in your ```routes\web.php``` or ```routes\api.php``` based on your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I am following this approach, just wondering if there is better way of doing what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this:

Project

--routes

----api.php => you have API router here

----web.php => your web router

--views

----create-product.blade.php => then call to vue component
--vue
--create-product.vue